# iptables matching syntax

Tags: iptables, firewall

For the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 255 -j ACCEPT
```

I am not sure what the point of "-m" is given that "-p" is already present. Does it serve any purpose in this case? Can the above be simplified to one of the below while retaining all the functions?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 255 -j ACCEPT
```

OR

```
iptables -A INPUT -m icmp --icmp-type 255 -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-p` specifies the protocol while `-m` specifies the **matching module** which is used. The matching module might have a different type or you could specify multiple modules there. This is why you need separate flags. See the iptables manpage section `MATCH EXTENSIONS` for the various uses of -m.

However, in your case `-p x` implies `-m x`, so the second rule works equally well as the first one. The third rule is invalid. Though -m can stand alone in some cases, you have to use it along -p here as you cannot use a (protocol) matching module without explicitly specifying the protocol.

Comment: Extensions like `state`, `conntrack`, etc.

Comment: Correct, `-m state` does not need a protocol. `-m multiport <portlist>` does, for another famous example. See the manpage for more.

Comment: To clarify things a bit, think of `-m` and `-j` as plugins that load additional functionality and allow additional command parameters to be understood. For example, `--comment` is meaningless to the `iptables` command until `-m comment` is specified. You can find a description of loadable `-m` (matching) and `-j` (target) modules and the additional parameters they enable in the `iptables` manual page.

Comment: Actually, IIRC, `-j` doesn't load a module; it jumps to an already known target.

Comment: thank you for the answer and for the comments. i have been reading up on the iptables command but it seems that the following syntax is valid:

iptables -A INPUT -m tcp ......

but your answer suggests this is not correct? can you please clarify. Thanks again.

Comment: Which part of the manpage lets you think that it's valid? In v1.4.8 and v1.4.12 I cannot think of any possible rule omitting -p that does not result in error `ip_tables: tcp match: only valid for protocol 6` (protocol 1 in case of icmp). So could you clarify what kind of rule should be valid here?

Comment: I saw some website uses the following -m tcp -p tcp so I thought that it could be simplified as -m tcp. It turned out to be wrong. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Just on a side note, it's interesting that if "-p tcp -j DROP" is used instead of the more complete syntax "-m tcp -p tcp -j DROP", then the last column description of the rule (run iptables -L command) will omit the "tcp" descriptor for the former case. Not sure if there is any difference...

Comment: True. It shows that iptables respects your more detailed command even though it's redundant.